# postgres tables not found after migrate

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration, backup, restore

i'm using laravel 10 with postgres db on ubuntu, i was working fine , until i added a migration that creates a new table and then migrate it.

Suddenly, all my existing tables were gone **except this new new table** and the migrations table.

i really  don't know what happened here, when i expand the tables nav from pgadmin4 , i only see the new table + migration.

i don't have a backup, so i'm realy lost.

i checked the **log file** and didn't found any **drop table query** , so i dont know if they're **deleted or just hidden**.

i followed several tutorials on the net, but coudn't figure it out.

if someone has faced the same issue, or he can help me restore the tables, please.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found a `drop database` query?

Comment: No, i didn't find anything in the log file.